# Is there a known resolution to this Flyway warning about the Snowflake JDBC driver?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, flyway

The following warning messages are produced during execution of Flyway using any version of the Snowflake JDBC driver 3.11.1 through 3.12.5:

`WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred 
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by net.snowflake.client.jdbc.internal.io.netty.util.internal.ReflectionUtil (file:/usr/local/Cellar/flyway/6.4.2/libexec/drivers/snowflake-jdbc-3.12.5.jar) to constructor java.nio.DirectByteBuffer(long,int) 
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of net.snowflake.client.jdbc.internal.io.netty.util.internal.ReflectionUtil 
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations 
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release`

Answer (score 1):

Correct, this is just a warning message and can be safely ignored.  It is being tracked here for resolution if you'd like to follow (whether Snowflake decides to suppress the warnings or otherwise in a future update):  https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-jdbc/issues/202